# How to apply LinedResource to XSLT in C# method?

Tags: c#, xslt, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml, html-email

I have one XSLT file that takes elements from XML and gives HTML output i use

```
XslCompiledTransform()
```

to convert XSLT to html output in C# method. The output is then converted to HTML Email Message Body and sent to the client dynamically. 
I have some images embedded in the html everything works fine as long as my site at some domain. But when i test it from my Development Machine the images doesn't get sent to the client.

To overcome this i am using a class called

```
LinkedResource();
```

which helps to embed images in html. I works fine if you are writing custom html inside your html body. But in my case my html is being generated by XSLT.

Can anyone tell me how can i apply this (linedresource) to XSLT so that the html produced will contain the images.

SO far i have tried something like this:

```
           var logoImageResource =new LinkedResource("C:\\MyProject\\Images\\logo.png")
                    {
                    ContentId = "logoId",
                    TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64
            };
```

And my XLST file has used the ContentId like this:

```
 <img src="cid:logoId" alt="logo"/>
```

Till now it doesn't work for me. Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using linkedresource statement before doing XSLT transformation worked fine.